# Why can't I make a purchase consumable?

Tags: android

Hey I want to make a button that increase the coins the user has so I checked how to implement in app purchases for android and make a purchase consumable and everything is working fine until when I try to purchase the item again, when I press the button it gives an error saying that the item has already been purchased, I looked up the internet for people who had the same problem but I couldn't find something that would work for me and I also saw the sample code that google provided and I can't see anything different from my code and theirs maybe it is something that I can't see, so if someone would help me in locating the error that would great, thanks.

Here is My Activity:

```
private static final String TAG = "Billing";
IabHelper mHelper;
static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    ....
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = res.getString(R.string.licenseKey);
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
            }
        }
    });

    ...
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}



IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

        shared = getSharedPreferences("PrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = shared.edit();
        int Coins = shared.getInt("CoinsValue", 1000);

        if (result.isFailure()) {

            return;
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Purchase Complete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            consumeItem();
            coinsValue = Coins + 500;
            editor.putInt("CoinsValue", coinsValue).commit();
        }

    }
};

public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,Inventory inventory) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {

                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
            }
        };

//This is an OnClick for a button in the xml
public void PurchaseCoins(View view){
        interstitial = null;
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
        mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}
```

Comment: consume process is not successful always so you have to check status in mConsumeFinishedListener .

Comment: @mohammadsadeghsaati can you please tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no gurantee that consume process would be successful so you need to consume your purchase until it is done.

so I consume items after successful purchase in Purchase listener :

```
mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
```

and everytime users starts the application after setuping IAB try again to consume purchases that have not been consumes successfuly

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

and this is it's callback :

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new     IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure())
        {
            return;
        }

          Purchase gasPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(YOUR_ITEM);
          if (gasPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(gasPurchase)) {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(getPurchase,mConsumeFinishedListener);
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

which consumes YOUR_ITEM

and finally if you are that bad luck which items has not been consumed yet after trying to purchase it again IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener returns status indicates it and you can retry for consuming item again.

this scenario is working for me but you have to know if your user may purchase some items again before closing application it is better retry for consuming in consume callback if it has been failed

Comment: It's not working and I getting this error `Purchase verification failed: missing data`

Comment: But can you tell me how to make the it for a single purchase only

Comment: @TozFik what do you mean ,you want to consume one item in  mGotInventoryListener  ??

Comment: yes, you said that this method will consume all of the items, how to make it only consume one

Comment: in the loop where every purchased item is traversed in inventory you can check them to see if it's the one must be consumed or not

Comment: I don't understand, can you please edit your code so it would support only one item

Comment: just editted the answer but you do NOT implemenet IAB based on stackoverflow answers, you must read documents by yourself.